# Ping/Curl works but website is not accessible via webbrowser

Tags: html, apache, http, ubuntu, ip

I am trying to host my own web page on an Ubuntu server. I can access the webpage if I type the IP address in my web browser, but I can't if I type the domain name (a free one from [Freenom](https://www.freenom.com)).

But if I use the command `curl my.domain.name` then I get the index.html contents. So, why can't I access the page via my web browser (Firefox/Chromium)?

Note that the `ping` command also works fine (no packet loss). Finally, I am not hosting the web page on the same computer as the one trying to access it. So far, my best guess is that the problem comes from the web browsers or Freenom, do not hesitate to ask for more info, I will edit my post.

Comment: what is the error you get in your web browser?

Comment: The usual "Server Not found", although it loads for a while? I suppose it's the TTL I set that is 300.

Comment: are you accessing site from the same server or from a remote server?

Comment: I am trying to access from another computer. The server and my computer are not even in the same local network.